# How to generate conditionally Numeric column in select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

In Mysql, I am doing as below to generate numeric column conditionally :

```
create table align1 (col1 varchar(100),col2 varchar(100));

insert into align1 values ('1','1');
insert into align1 values ('1','1');
insert into align1 values ('1','1');
insert into align1 values ('1','1');
insert into align1 values ('10','1');
insert into align1 values ('10','1');
insert into align1 values ('100','1');
```

What I want to achieve is if value for col1 is same for previous row and current row then increment new virtual column value

query:

```
select col1,col2,if(@temp1=col1,@i:=@i+1, @i:=1) as  _keycol,@temp1:=col1 from align1,(select @temp1:=null,@i:=0)t
```

everything is perfect in mysql.

[sql fiidle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8f7b69f/1)

Now I want to generate same column(in above example "_KEYCOL" is column name) in sql server.

SO simple is that I just want to generate one new column in select statement and value for this column is need to be set conditionally from other column values in sql server same I have achieved in mysql.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why are you going to the dark side?

Comment: In SQL, tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no "previous" row, unless a column explicitly specifies the ordering.  A query returns rows in an arbitrary order.  Your MySQL query is not correct (well, not stable), because there is no order by.  Do you have a column that specifies the ordering of the rows?  What happens if subsequent rows have a value of `1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its way easier in `SQLServer` using `Row_number`:

```
select col1,col2, row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col1) as _KEYCOL
from align1
```

[Demo Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/03cb1/1)

more info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

Comment: right now it works.. thank you for answer, but what about complex conditions. I mean if I want to increment or reset value by complex conditions then is there any solution in sql server? again thanks

Comment: You can use more that one column to partition by  (and order by) for complex conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col1,col2)_Keycol
FROM dbo.align1
```

Comment: right now it works.. thank you for answer, but what about complex conditions. I mean if I want to increment or reset value by complex conditions then is there any solution in sql server? again thanks